# go to VC from button inside xib file that is used as a tableHeaderView

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, tableview, xib

I have a `TableSectionHeader` `xib` file with a `button` in it (and some other stuff). This xib file is used as the `custom header` of a `UItableview` inside my `PostViewController`.

I want to be able to click on that button to show the detail about the cell. However, as the button is INSIDE the xib file, the `IBAction` is inside the `TableSectionHeader.Swift` (which inherits from UITableViewHeaderFooterView). This means that I can not `segue or instantiate` a VC.

How could I go from this button that is inside the `xib` file to another VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an outlet of your button into your xib class not an action , and when you create and return the header in your view controller , you will have a reference of your button before you return the header, then `addTarget` to your button and tag with selector to the method that is going to handle going to your next view controller .

In your xib class drag and connect the button :

```
class YearSectionHeader : UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

@IBOutlet car button :UIButton!

}
```

In your view controller table view header method (example) don't forget to change the class to and identifier to the correct one your using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header : YearSectionHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("TableHeader") as! YearSectionHeader
        header.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlingMethodName(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        header.button.tag = section
        return header

    }
```

`sender.tag` is your section number, you can perform the segue here  :

```
func handlingMethodName(sender:UIButton){

        print(sender.tag)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just piggybacking off of Aaoli's answer here - this code works. I couldn't believe it. You need to connect the IBAction to the XIB file, and also have the exact same IBAction line but without the connection in the View Controller.

XIB File (connect to the cell, but do not add any code:

```
    @IBAction func completePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

View Controller:

```
    @IBAction func completePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("holler")
}
```

Now, in your View controller where your table view is, put the following code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header : TestCell = itemTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell") as! TestCell
    header.compLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.completePressed(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    header.compLabel.tag = section

    return header

}
```

The fact that this works is amazing, and i have no idea why